# How do I fix this weird material/ texture of the glass?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I was adding a condensation normal Map to the cup near the rim. I was doing this in material preview which made nothing look wrong. Then when I did a test render it didn't look correct. Like the bottom half of the liquid was cut off and that for some reason the condensation texture was there.

[image]

It's like the bottom portion of the liquid material I had inside somehow got removed during the UV editing. I've looked at the UV tab, shading tab, and all through my materials tab and I can't find what caused the problem. Nothing looks wrong in the material preview mode which is even more confusing. I haven't been able to find anyone with similar problems.

Here is the .blend file for anyone who wants to go hands on.
[image]

I am relatively new to Blender so don't be surprised if it is something fairly obvious.

Comment: Hi there:). Can u share your .blend file to get quick response?

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 Here is the .blend file for you to experiment with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/MO8llK0r sorry for the delay with replying as it is very late here.

Answer (score 1):

The lower faces of the liquid are interfering with the lower faces of the inside of the cup. You can fix this by scaling the liquid in the Z axis so that these lower faces are a little above the lower inner faces of the cup.
To do this:

1. Select the **Liquid** object and in **Edit mode** with **Face select** mode active, select the face in the middle of the top face of the Liquid.
2. With the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shft</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> choose the  **Cursor to Selected** option.
3. In the **Header** change the **Pivot Point** to **3D Cursor** (see screenshot below).

[image]

4. Still in **Edit mode** select **A**ll of the Liquid object.
5. Now scale a little along the Z axis so that the bottom of the liquid is not touching the bottom of the cup.

Tab out of edit mode and try a render :

[image]